# Guake and Tmux mouse cursor

Tags: terminal, mouse, ubuntu-16.04, tmux

I'm running the Guake terminal with Tmux windows in full screen as a persistent set of terminals when working on Ubuntu. I use F12 to toggle this terminal so can switch between terminal and for example browsing the web.

Only problem is when I am coding sometimes I hit the touchpad and the cursor will move or I highlight text in the window by mistake. I never use the mouse or touchpad when coding and don't want to display the pointer or respond to input from these when coding. Is that possible, how?

Thanks

P.S. I've tried `setw -g mouse off` in tmux

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop I can disable my touchpad. Also in the system settings I can disable the touchpad.